# Does Version Bookkeeping go before or after imports?

Tags: python, mercurial

I am hoping to use Version Bookkeeping in some python scripts I commit to Mercurial.

I intend to follow the instruction in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#version-bookkeeping but I am not sure if

> before any other code, separated by a blank line above and below.

means before imports. Does it? I am asking because some imports seem to have to be placed at the very beginning, for example:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import, unicode_literals
```

Comment: I don't know, but if you put `__version__` in the package's `__init__.py` module you're unlikely to have any `__future__` imports in there.

Answer (score 0):

> These lines should be included after the module's docstring, before **any** other code, separated by a blank line above and below.

`import` statements are code.  You can put them inside of `try`/`except` statements in order to catch `ImportError`, and less commonly they can be used inside functions and class statements.  So this goes after the module docstring and before the imports.

> I am asking because some imports seem to have to be placed at the very beginning[...]

`__future__` statements are not (just) ordinary code.  They are understood by the compiler (as opposed to the interpreter), and [*have* to come before you start assigning variables or importing other modules](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#future):

> A future statement must appear near the top of the module. The only
>   lines that can appear before a future statement are:
>
> - the module docstring (if any),
> - comments,
> - blank lines, and
> - other future statements.

So, if your version control crud is a comment, you can put it before the future statements.  But if it's a real variable, it has to go after.